# Update and increment value with realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to update the points of the child : add 40points to the old result points, but I get the error :
**undefined is not an object (Evaluating 'pointRef.update')**

```
const pointRef=firebase.database().ref("Users").child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                            .once("value",(snapshot=>
                            {
                            pointRef.update({Points:snapshot.val().Points+40
                             })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `.once()` method on pointRef so it is no longer a [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference). It is a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) now. So you cannot call the `.update()` method on it. Instead try using the following code:

```
const pointRef = firebase.database().ref("Users").child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)

pointRef.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  pointRef.update({Points:snapshot.val().Points+40}).then(() => {
    console.log("Points updated")
  })
})
```

The better way of doing this:

```
firebase.database().ref("Users").child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .set({Points: firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(40)})
```

Here you don't need to manually fetch, add and update the points field.

Comment: Thank for the help! The first method is working for me, but for the second one, I get the error "TypeError: _app.default.database.ServerValue.increment is not a function"

Comment: @user123456 You might be on an older version of the JavaScript SDK. Upgrade to a recent version to get access to the `increment()` operation.